# How do I configure VIM to use different syntaxes in different parts of a file?

Tags: vim, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I have a file that works like this:

```
:: JavaScript
function whatIsThis(){
    return "an example";
}

:: Haskell
main = putStrLn "is this is an example?"

:: C
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("yes, it is");
};
```

In other words, a line starting with `::` determines the syntax of the next lines until another `::` is found. Is there any way to configure vim to highlight the syntax of those blocks correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at my [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168); it offers both a `:[range]SyntaxInclude` command, and functions to define regions (based on start and end patterns) to highlight with a particular syntax. For your example:

```
call SyntaxRange#IncludeEx('start="^:: Haskell" end="^::"me=e-3', 'haskell')
call SyntaxRange#IncludeEx('start="^:: C" end="^::"me=e-3', 'c')
call SyntaxRange#IncludeEx('start="^:: JavaScript" end="^::"me=e-3', 'javascript')
```

Comment: Woa, spot on. I'll test it soon. Why did you write this? It has just occurred me, thought, that there will still be a problem with comments, correct? That is, I use NerdCommenter and I guess it depends on filetypes. But that is already a lot. Thank you.

Comment: The plugin basically is a refinement from the linked Vim Tips Wiki page. I use it e.g. to highlight diffs inside emails. For full filetype-specific settings, I'd go with another approach; see my second answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have full editing capabilities for each separate part (i.e. filetype-specific settings, customizations, mappings, commands), not just specific syntax highlighting, you won't get around having a separate buffer for each fragment (as these things are all tied to the buffer's filetype).

With the [NrrwRgn - A Narrow Region Plugin similar to Emacs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075), you can cut up the original file into separate buffers (shown e.g. in split windows), and the plugin syncs any changes back to the original automatically.